# gnuplot highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, gnuplot, syntax-highlighting

I am using gnuplot to display data and I usually edit the files in vim. I would like to have some sort of syntax highlighting if it was possible. I tried to install several plugins with vim plug for gnuplot but I can't seem to make it work. here is the contents of my `.vimrc` file:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'

Plug 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'

Plug 'junegunn/seoul256.vim'

Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'

Plug 'vim-scripts/gnuplot.vim'

call plug#end()

if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

let mapleader=","
set cindent
set statusline+=col:\ %c,
set ruler
set nu
set showcmd
set nocompatible
set nosol
set background=dark
set autoread
set wildmenu
set lazyredraw
set magic
set showmatch
set mat=10
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set autoindent
set smartindent
set cursorline
set ic
set hls
set lbr
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set t_Co=256
set shortmess+=A
set ff=unix
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set splitbelow
set termwinsize=10x0
set mouse=i

set formatoptions+=w
set splitright
set autochdir

set textwidth=180 wrapmargin=0
set colorcolumn=180
" 
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
""
colorscheme Monokai
"
augroup gnuplot
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType gp :nnoremap <Leader>c :w<CR>:!gnuplot %<CR>
    autocmd FileType gp :nnoremap <Leader>v :!okular $(awk 'BEGIN {FS="\047"} /set output/ {print $2}' "%") &<CR><CR> 
augroup END
""
let g:livepreview_previewer = 'okular'

""
map <C-m> :set nonu<CR>
map <C-n>   :set nu<CR>
```

I am almost sure that the problem comes from this file but I cannot see it.

If I run: `:set hl` I get the following error:

```
highlight=8:SpecialKey,~:EndOfBuffer,@:NonText,d:Directory,e:ErrorMsg,i:IncSearch,l:Search,m:MoreMsg,M:ModeMsg,n:LineNr,a:LineNrAbove,b:LineNrBelow,N:CursorLineNr,r:Question,s:StatusLine,S:StatusLineNC,c:VertSplit,t:Title,v:Visual,V:VisualNOS,w:WarningMsg,W:WildMenu,f:Folded,F:F
oldColumn,A:DiffAdd,C:DiffChange,D:DiffDelete,T:DiffText,>:SignColumn,-:Conceal,B:SpellBad,P:SpellCap,R:SpellRare,L:SpellLocal,+:Pmenu,=:PmenuSel,x:PmenuSbar,X:PmenuThumb,*:TabLine,#:TabLineSel,_:TabLineFill,!:CursorColumn,.:CursorLine,o:ColorColumn,q:QuickFixLine,z:StatusLineTerm
,Z:StatusLineTermNC
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Vim assigns the `gnuplot` filetype to `*.gpi` files out of the box.
2. Syntax highlighting for gnuplot is also built-in.

Therefore…

- Your two `FiletType` autocommands can't work as-is. They should match on `gnuplot`, not `gp`:

  ```
  augroup gnuplot
      autocmd!
      autocmd FileType gnuplot nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>c :w<CR>:!gnuplot %<CR>
      autocmd FileType gnuplot nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>v :!okular $(awk 'BEGIN {FS="\047"} /set output/ {print $2}' "%") &<CR><CR> 
  augroup END
  ```

  (I also removed the unnecessary colons and added the missing `<buffer>`s that guarantee your mappings won't leak to buffers with other filetypes.)
- There is no hard need for installing a third-party syntax script.
- With your `vimrc` in its current form, Vim should highlight `*.gpi` without you having to do anything.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I have one question. I usually save my files with the extension `gp` not `gpi`. Is there a way to change the default to `gp`? I have a lot of files and I would have to change them all...

Comment: I did it! I have created a file called `gnuplot.vim` in `~/.vim/ftdetect/` and added the following line: `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.gp set filetype=gnuplot`. I now have syntax highlighting! Thank you!